# How to share an authorizer between templates without hitting limit of authorizers per API

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a dozen services which each have their own serverless template file, sharing the same root API on API Gateway.
My root `serverless.yml` file defines the API and an authorizer:

```
...
resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}
        Description: Medimap API Gateway
    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"

  Outputs:
    RestApiId:
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      Export:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-RestApiId
    RootResourceId:
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt: ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId
      Export:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId
    AuthenticationService:
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt: AuthenticationServiceLambdaFunction.Arn
      Export:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-AuthenticationService

functions:
  authenticationService:
    handler: src/api/common/authenticationService.handler
    environment:
      JWT_SECRET: ${env:JWT_SECRET}
    events:
      - http:
          path: authenticationService
          method: post
          cors: true
```

In the template for each of my services, I have code like the following:

```
provider:
  ...
  apiGateway:
    restApiId:
      "Fn::ImportValue": "medimap-api-${self:provider.stage}-RestApiId"
    restApiRootResourceId:
      "Fn::ImportValue": "medimap-api-${self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId"

custom:
  authorizer:
    name: example-authorizer
    arn:
      Fn::ImportValue: medimap-api-${self:provider.stage}-AuthenticationService

functions:
  exampleFunction:
    handler: src/api/example/exampleFunction.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: example/exampleFunction
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer}
```

This works fine, but once I have 10 services deployed, trying to deploy an 11th with the same authorizer gives me the following error:

```
Maximum number of Authorizers for this API has been reached.  Please contact AWS if you need additional Authorizers.
```

Now, I could just contact AWS to get the limit increased, but since they are technically all the same authorizer, I feel like there should be a way for me to make it work without creating a separate authorizer for each template file.

I tried using the same authorizer name for all of them, but I just end up getting the error:

```
Authorizer name must be unique. Authorizer example-authorizer already exists in this RestApi
```

Is there a way for me to share this authorizer among all of my services on the same API without having to create a newly named one for each service so that I don't hit this limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of sharing just the Lambda function per each (new) authorizer you can share the authorizer itself:

Api Gateway stack:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}
        Description: Medimap API Gateway
    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"
    ApiGatewayAuthorizer:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:
        AuthorizerUri:
          Fn::Join:
            - ''
            - - 'arn:'
              - { Ref: AWS::Partition }
              - ":apigateway:"
              - { Ref: AWS::Region }
              - ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/"
              - { 'Fn::GetAtt': [${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-authenticationService, 'Arn'] }
              - "/invocations"
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        Name: LambdaAuthorizer
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Type: TOKEN

  Outputs:
    RestApiId:
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      Export:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-RestApiId
    RootResourceId:
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt: ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId
      Export:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId
    AuthenticationService:
      Value:
        { Ref: ApiGatewayAuthorizer }
      Export:
        Name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-AuthenticationService

functions:
  authenticationService:
    handler: src/api/common/authenticationService.handler
    environment:
      JWT_SECRET: ${env:JWT_SECRET}
    events:
      - http:
          path: authenticationService
          method: post
          cors: true
```

And in your other stacks:

```
functions:
  exampleFunction:
    handler: src/api/example/exampleFunction.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: example/exampleFunction
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer:           
            type: TOKEN 
            authorizerId:
              Fn::ImportValue: medimap-api-${self:provider.stage}-AuthenticationService
```

This is done from memory + CloudFormation docs, so please forgive for any compilation errors...

Source:

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#share-authorizer